# How to export the sql server query result to .csv file and data should be double quotes in exported file using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Hi Folks i have requirement How to export the sql server query result to .csv file and data should be  double quotes in exported file using SSIS

Below is Sample scenario please give me some suggestion to perform the task in SSIS.

```
Sql Query: SELECT EmployeeID,Name,Sal FROM EMPLOYEE
```

Expected Result

```
EmployeeID    Name         Sal
"1001"       "john"       "$20000"
"1002"       "Harry"      "$30000"
"1003"       "Kia"        "$20000"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the `"` in the text qualifier field of the Connection Manager:
[image]

Comment: HI @larnu  adding double quotes (") in text qualifier in file destination Editor will give my expected result ?

Comment: I wouldn't have posted this as an answer if it didn't, @Sreenu131 ... Have you not tried?

Comment: @Larnu. Does that quote wrap int and dates as well? or does he need a cast to string?

Comment: Pretty sure it wraps everything, @KeithL as CSV files don't have data types; everything is text. I can't recall with 100% certaincy off the top of my head though.